# Validation help form AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a form to add customers to a table-mysql, but I like put a validation for a input form, just accetp hexadecimal 0-9 and a-f just lowercase and on this pattern: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx when "x" can be 0-9 and a-f and no empty.

my form:

```
<form name="product_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
    <form-element label="MAC ADDRESS" mod="product">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               placeholder="Mac Address" ng-model="product.name" focus/>
    </form-element>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input ng-pattern="'([0-9a-f]{4}\.){2}[0-9a-f]{4}'" … />`

Comment: I add the line, but it doesnt working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation works fine. It will throw you error unless you match the whole pattern.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx

```
<form name="product_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
    <form-element label="MAC ADDRESS" mod="product">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               placeholder="Mac Address" ng-model="product.name" focus required ng-pattern="/[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}/" />
        <span ng-if="product_form.name.$error.required">This field is required</span>
        <span ng-if="product_form.name.$error.pattern">Pattern doesnot match</span>
    </form-element>
</form>
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/1yk8jnaa/1/)

Comment: I reset the PC windows chrome user, and delete the history and now are working.

Comment: Under development, its always better to use Ctrl+F5 to avoid cached file loading.

Answer (score 0):

To do that or any other pattern based verification you can use the `ng-pattern` built in directive input https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input.

in your case you just need to use the regex:

```
/[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}/
```

so your input becomes:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
           placeholder="Mac Address" ng-model="product.name" focus ng-pattern="/[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}/" required/>
```

Plunker for the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gazY4z9PJbbtINQC7ziu?p=preview

Comment: You probably will need to escape the period here.

Comment: I thought so too, but the ng-pattern has no problem with the periods.

Comment: Huh.  So it only allows periods there?  My expectation is that it would allow any single char there (not just periods).  If so, I've maybe been escaping things unnecessarily in ng-pattern.

Comment: It's allowing any char, not just periods, in your example.

Comment: Good catch thanks, I've changed everything to be correct.

Comment: I'm running it no problem in chrome. what errors are you seeing in chrome?

Comment: When I am use IE, the button to add the record come to be on gray (disable) if the pattern are not posive, when the patter come to be enable the button "add" come enable,... but on Chrome, if the input have incomplete, or emtpty or no like the rules, the "add" button let me press and add the record...

Comment: can you post your form sample to a plnkr? it seems like something else is going on.

Comment: Ok, thank for your help, to allm this is my fisrt time here about wed and using pinkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YFEHuHeOLhALffFJuMk5?p=preview  I take this demo and modified to my databases. http://www.angularcode.com/product-inventory-management-using-angularjs-mysql-and-php-restful-api/

Comment: You need to add the required flag on your input element. Also there was a change to the regex that wasn't in your plunkr. ng-pattern will just make it so your model adheres to the pattern. It doesn't validate that its empty. I've updated my answer so you can just copy if needed.

Comment: no man:( I copied that to my code and not working: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Mac Address" ng-model="product.name" focus ng-pattern="/[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}\.[a-f0-9]{4}/" required/>, how I do this:  "add the required flag on your input element."